# Finding the only visible <div> which contains a dynamic <ul> and returning the <ul> id

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-ui-sortable, selected, posting

I have a bunch of dynamic tabs (div's) such as:

```
<div id="collection">

  <div id="tab-1">
    <ul id="sortable-tab-1">
      <li>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="tab-2" class="hidden">
    <ul id="sortable-tab-2">
      <li>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  .... etc ...
</div>
```

I'm looking for the best way to find out which **tab (div)** is visible using jquery. Since the tabs are dynamic I don't know the id's but I do know which div's are hidden hence leaving me one div that is visible.

I need to somehow find the **ul id** of the visible div then return the ul id. So that I'm left with 'sortable-tab-1' as my result.

Basically I need to know which tab is selected so I can post the correct sortable list.

JavaScript gives me a head ache!

Can anyone help. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#collection > div:visible > ul').attr('id')
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly - and I thought it would be difficult!

Answer (score 0):

**Theory:** I assume all of your hidden tabs has "tab-something" as the id attribute value and "hidden" in the class name. So if you find a potential div which has no class="hidden" then you can find anything from that.

**Code:**

```
  $("div#collection > div[id^=tab-").each(function(index)
  {
    if($(this).hasClass("hidden")==false)
        return $(this).children("ul").attr("id");
  }
```

**Caution:** If you have more than one div with "hidden" class then only last div's  tag's id will be returned...